# How to style an iframe in React

Tags: css, reactjs, iframe

I am trying to style an iframe in React that is being fetched from an api call and displayed on the screen to the user. I would prefer to apply an entire stylesheet to it rather than specific rules, but at this point I am just looking for a starting point.

I have tried using a `querySelector` to select the iframe in a `componentDidMount` and then add a stylesheet directly, but I have not had success.

I am trying to avoid using `querySelectors` altogether and leave the direct DOM manipulation up to React itself.

Has anyone else needed to use their own styles to format content from an iframe they received from an api before? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more useful, if you posted the code you have, together with the issue and then we can answer a direct question.